# simple rails validation with regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, whitespace

I am trying to write a regex that matches the following:

first an optional "+" at the beginning, then some numbers and whitespaces in any order

I tried to use this regex (and lots of others...) 
/\A[+]?([\d|\t\n\r\f])*/

However, they seem to exclude both whitespaces and letters or allow both (if there are letters in the middle).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Post some sample string and expected results.

Comment: +5454 435435 (yes)
5435hello3424 (no)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is the regex that'll work for you: http://rubular.com/r/0CgrZhEp5G

```
/^\+?([\d\s]+)$/
```